# How to use Elasticsearch for production in jHipster?

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

We are using jhipster and the application is hosted on AWS. Right now we use the default embeded elasticsearch server and the indices are stored in the target folder, but i wonder what's the right way to use the elasticsearch for production? Shall we set up a separate instance running on port 9300 or Shall we use Amazon Elasticsearch Service? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: we can solve this by giving the volume to the elastic search. But I want to achieve that I am running app in one instance and elastic search in another instance, i have opened port and changed ip accordingly. Unable to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends your data volume, but if you can pay for AWS elasticsearch service, go for it!

Else, you need at least 3 VMs for a cluster master quorum.

Comment: I was unable to connect the elastic search running in one instance and app is ruining in another instance. is remote elastic search app connection possible in Jhipster

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at [elastic official cloud service](https://www.elastic.co/cloud).

Answer (score 0):

Running elasticsearch in docker container ? This will solve your problem by setting up the Volume to your elastic search service that will save into your volume

```
app-elasticsearch:
    container_name: app-elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.1
    volumes:
        - /home/ubuntu/db/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

better to have in separate instance from where the app is running